# Binary Search Tree Insert and Remove Functions

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am working on a project for my computer science class and ran into a bit of trouble with the insert and remove functions of a binary search tree.

The project involves inserting a word and an integer into a node and attaching those nodes in a binary search tree. Here is the [full project description](http://web.stcloudstate.edu/bajulstrom/cs301/projects/p7s09.html).

My program will insert words into the tree just fine, but the words are empty. The code for these operations came straight from the instructor and I am not sure where the issue may be. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

**Header File:**

```
#ifndef CONCORDANCE_H
#define CONCORDANCE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int MAX = 8;

class Concordance
{
    public:
        typedef char Item[MAX+1];

        // Constructor
        Concordance() { root = NULL; }

        // Destructor
        ~Concordance();

        // Modification Member Functions
        void insert(Item entry, int n);
        void remove(Item target);
        int get_count(Item target);

        // Constant Member Functions
        int length();

        // Friend Functions
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out_s, Concordance& c); 

    private:
        // Data Members
        struct Node
        {
            Item data;
            int count;
            Node *left;
            Node *right;
        };
        Node *root;
        void destroy(Node *r);
        void help_remove(Node *&t, Item target);
        void remove_node(Node *&t);
        void print(Node *p, std::ostream& out_s);
        void help_insert(Node* &t, Item entry, int n);
        int count(Node *r);
};
#endif
```

**Implementation File:**

```
#include "concordance.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void Concordance::destroy(Node *r)
{
    if(r != NULL)
    {
        destroy(r -> left);
        destroy(r -> right);
        delete r;
    }
}

Concordance::~Concordance()
{
    destroy(root);
}

void Concordance::help_insert(Node* &t, Item entry, int n)
{
    if ( t == NULL )
    {
        t = new Node;
        strcpy(t -> data, entry);
        t -> count = n;
        t -> left = NULL;
        t -> right = NULL;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(entry, t -> data) < 0)
        help_insert ( t -> left, entry, n );
    else
        help_insert ( t -> right, entry, n );
}

void Concordance::insert(Item entry, int n)
{
    help_insert(root, entry, n);
}

void Concordance::help_remove(Node *&t, Item target)
{
    if(strcmp(t -> data, target) == 0)
        remove_node(t);
    else if(strcmp(target, t -> data) < 0)
        help_remove(t -> left, target);
    else
        help_remove(t -> right, target);
}

void Concordance::remove_node(Node *&t)
{
    Node *ptr;
    Node *back;
    if(t -> left == NULL && t -> right == NULL)
    {
        delete t;
        t = NULL;
    }
    else if(t -> left == NULL)
    {
        ptr = t;
        t = t -> right;
        delete ptr;
    }
    else if(t -> right == NULL)
    {
        ptr = t;
        t = t -> left;
        delete ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        back = t;
        ptr = t -> right;
        while(ptr -> left != NULL)
        {
            back = ptr;
            ptr = ptr -> left;
        }
        strcpy(t -> data, ptr -> data);
        if(back == t)
            remove_node(back -> right);
        else
            remove_node(back -> left);
    }
}

void Concordance::remove(Item target)
{
    help_remove(root, target);
}

int Concordance::get_count(Item target)
{
    Node *p = root;
    int temp;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(p -> data, target) == 0)
            temp = p -> count;
        else if(strcmp(target, p -> data) < 0)
            p = p -> left;
        else
            p = p -> right;
    }
    return temp;
}

int Concordance::count(Node *r)
{
    if(r == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return count(r -> left) + 1 + count(r -> right);
}

int Concordance::length()
{
    return count(root);
}

void Concordance::print(Node *p, ostream& out_s)
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        print(p -> left, out_s);
        out_s << left << setw(10) << p -> data << right << setw(9) << p -> count << endl;
        print(p -> right, out_s);
    }
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out_s, Concordance& c)
{
    Concordance::Node *output;

    out_s << "Word" << setw(10) << " " << "Count" << setw(8) << endl;
    out_s << "--------------------" << endl;

    c.print(c.root, out_s);

    out_s << "--------------------" << endl;

    return out_s;
}
```

**Main Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "concordance.h"
using namespace std;

typedef char Word[MAX+1];

void read_word(ifstream& infile, Word array)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;

    infile.get(ch);

    while(isalpha(ch) && !isspace(ch) && !ispunct(ch))
    { 
        if(i > MAX-1)
        {
            while(!isspace(ch) && !ispunct(ch))
                infile.get(ch);
            break;
        }

        ch = toupper(ch);

        array[i] = ch;
        i++;
        infile.get(ch);
    }
    if(i != 0)
        array[i] = '\0';    // Null Character
}

void make_list(ifstream& infile, Word& array)
{
    Concordance concord;
    int count = 0;
    int length;

    read_word(infile, array);               // Read a word
    while(!infile.eof())                    // While the file isn't empty...
    {
        concord.insert(array, count);       // Insert into concordance
        read_word(infile, array);           // Read another word
    }

    cout << concord;
    length = concord.length();

    cout << "The file contains " << length << " distinct words." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char file_name[100];
    typedef char Word[MAX+1];
    ifstream infile;
    Word array;

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file_name;               // Get file name

    infile.open(file_name);         // Open file
    if(!infile)                     // If we couldn't open the file...
    {
        cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    make_list(infile, array);       // Make the concordance

    infile.close();                 // Close the input file

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to trace the problem. Also, you haven't shown your main function.

Comment: Please show us your test program which produces the segmentation fault. Ideally, also do a step by step debugging of your program in order to determine, where exactly the seg fault hapens. REMOVED: "Also the definition of `Item` is missing"

Comment: Never mind! It turned out to be an issue with the main function. The program is working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not caused by your binary tree implementation, but by the implementation of `read_word`: Just add the check for eof in the loop's condition and you should be fine.

E.g.:

```
while(!infile.eof() && isalpha(ch) && !isspace(ch) && !ispunct(ch))
```